# Error when accessing Banno API to retrieve token

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are receiving the following error when attempting to retrieve tokens from the Banno integration at a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/token:  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

This error only occurs when connecting from a 2012 R2 Server, request works on any servers utilizing Server 2016 or later.

We have performed the standard steps of adding the following prior to calling the HTTP Client
`ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

We are able to reproduce the issue on other servers by removing the above, but once added we are able to connect to the API link on all servers except for our 2012 R2 Server.

We have checked the registry keys to ensure that TLS1.2 is enabled on the server which is confirmed by the above working at other integrations that utilize the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen reports from other developers who have issues with Windows Server 2012. It's old enough (more than a decade as of this writing) that it seems to not be quite in full compliance with TLS 1.2.

We recommend upgrading to a newer version of Windows Server. (It sounds like you had success using Windows Server 2016 or later.)